# Privileged instruction runtime error on strcpy()

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm having an issue upgrading a C++ Builder 6 project to C++ Builder XE3. Currently my problem is this: When compiled and run in Release mode, the project throws the "Privileged instruction." error which I've tracked down to two different for loops surrounding calls to strcpy(). I've attempted changing this to strncpy() and including the character string size, but to no avail. All I know is that when I comment out these two lines, the error goes away.

Pertinent code:

```
/** Main.h */
class TForm1 : public TForm {
    published:
        void __fastcall ReadCalFromUnitBtnClick(TObject *Sender);
    private:
        struct CALIBRATION {
            char name[64];
            float gain1;
            float gain2;
            float offset;
            ...
            ... // A few more values that aren't pertinent to this question.
        };
        CALIBRATION calibr[256];
        void __fastcall TForm1::ReadCalibrationFromUnit(CALIBRATION *reg);
};
extern char *ADC_names[];
```

and

```
/** Main.cpp */
char *ADC_names[] = {
    "String 1",
    "String 2",
    "String 3",
    "String 4",
    "String 5",
    "String 6",
    "String 7",
    "String 8"
};

void __fastcall TForm1::ReadCalFromUnitBtnClick(TObject *Sender) {
    memset(calibr,0,sizeof(calibr));
    ReadCalibrationFromUnit(calibr);
}    

void __fastcall TForm1::ReadCalibrationFromUnit(CALIBRATION *reg) {

    // for (int j=0, j < 8, j++) { // Incorrect; but no bearing on actual soln.

    for (int j=0; j < 8; j++) {
        // Here's the problematic line. Another loop exists which does the same
        //   thing for another 18 array members in reg, but is essentially 
        //   identical to this one.
        strcpy(reg[j].name, ADC_names[j]); 
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot of things such as making ADC_names a const char, omitting the extern delcaration on it, attempting a strncpy() into the reg[] array...

From what I can tell, all the memory has been properly allocated to account for everything, `ADC_names[]` is far from null, as we define it before even entering the form constructor. Tried editting `calibr[]` directly in the for loop, rather than the `reg` function variable it is passed into, and yet the error still exists.

What's really weird is that this error only shows up when I compile and run in Release mode. Debug does not give this error at all.

Also the error changes as the program execution progresses. "Privileged error" is only displayed at startup when the function is called through an auto-connect button click. Later, when the button is clicked manually, the error changes to "Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000."

I've tried wrapping my head around this, but everything seems to look okay with my limited knowledge of memory handling. Any idea of what could be causing this?

Thanks.
-Daniel

Comment: Since you are upgrading/porting, why not just go to `std::string`?

Comment: How is `ReadCalibrationFromUnit` called? What is `reg` exactly when it's invoked?

Comment: I've thought about upgrading every instance to something like a UnicodeString, but I seem to remember running into wide character errors when I attempted that before on another project. I guess my reasoning is, I have no idea where all these values are actually used, and how far I'll have to go to upgrade everything, as I'm only partway through the code to just clean up its formatting. The FPGA that this connects to only accepts standard characters, not Unicode or wide characters or anything, so I'm unsure if this "register name" field is ever sent to the unit at all. But I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: `ReadCalibrationFromUnit` is called with the button click event `ReadCalFromUnitBtnClick()`. This, in turn, is called from the `ConnectBtnClick()` event (another button), which is in turn, called from the `Form1Load()` event. However, both buttons can also be clicked manually as well. As for `reg`, it is the function variable that `calibr` is passed into on the button click event detailed in the question.

Comment: If y program crashes in release mode but not in debug mode, then it's often a sign of you using an uninitialized local variable. The reason being that the debugger zeroes out all data, including local variables, which means that pointers are `NULL` when in the debugger. If you have a check for `NULL` pointer, then an uninitialized local variable will pass through as the contents of uninitialized variables are non-null (their value is undefined, and mostly random).

Comment: With my comment above in mind, how do you create and use the `TForm1` object?

Comment: Maybe it's a form of the classic "static initialisation order fiasco"?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `TForm1` is the main VCL object that C++ Builder automatically creates when the project is created. And its constructor has nothing which points to the calibration stuff. However, you make a very good point. The `calibr[]` array is never actually defined when created; just declared. But...doesn't the `memset()` in the `ReadCalFromUnitBtnClick()` event zero out any undefined array values?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Feel free to post your bit as an answer. I managed to figure it out using the information you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by researching the comment from @UlrichEckhardt:

> Maybe it's a form of the classic "static initialisation order fiasco"?

Turns out that `memset(calibr,0,sizeof(calibr))` was taking longer to execute than the function call `ReadCalibrationFromUnit(calibr);`. Officially, this "static initialisation order fiasco" states that you have a 50/50 chance of the program doing it right. However, in my case, this problem was occurring every time.

To fix it, I simply moved the code from the `ReadCalibrationFromUnit()` function back into the `ReadCalFromUnitBtnClick()` event, since this event was the ONLY thing that ever called the second function, making the second function's very existence redundant and unnecessary.

So now my code appears:

```
/** Main.cpp */
char *ADC_names[] = {
   "String 1",
    "String 2",
    "String 3",
    "String 4",
    "String 5",
    "String 6",
    "String 7",
    "String 8"
};

void __fastcall TForm1::ReadCalFromUnitBtnClick(TObject *Sender) {
    memset(calibr, 0, sizeof(calibr));
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        strcpy(calibr[j].name, ADC_names[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a copy & paste error when you posted the code here, but have you realized that your for-loop is "wrong" ?

```
for (int j=0, j < 8, j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j=0; j < 8; j++)
```

right ? Wondering, why you wouldn't get a compiler error, but I'm not familar with C++ builder's compiler...

Comment: Oh. Ha. Yeah...I typed it here incorrectly. It would have most certainly caught that if it were in the actual code.